# Quartz2D performance - how to improve

Tags: ios

I am working in iOS and have been presented with this problem.  I will be receiving a relatively large set of data (a 500x500 or greater C-style array).  I need to construct what is essentially an X/Y plot from this data, where each datapoint in the 500x500 grid corresponds to a color based on it's value.  The thing is that this changes over time, making some animation as it were, so the calculations have to be fast in order to change when a new set of data comes in.

So basically, for every point in the array, I need to figure out which color it should map to, then figure out the square to draw on the grid to represent the data.  If my grid were 768x768 pixels, but I have a 500x500 dataset, then each datapoint would represent about a 1.5x1.5 rectangle (that's rounded, but I hope you get the idea).

I tried this by creating a new view class and overriding drawRect.  However, that met with horrible performance with anything much over a 20x20 dataset.

I have seen some suggestions about writing to image buffers, but I have not been able to find any examples of doing that (I'm pretty new to iOS).  Do you have any suggestions or could you point me to any resources which could help?

Thank you for your time,

Darryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that you can put in a method that will generate and return a UIImage in an offscreen context.  To improve performance, try to come up with ways to minimize the number of iterations, such as making your "pixels" bigger, or only drawing a portion that changes.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size); // Use your own image size here      

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       

// push context to make it current 
// (need to do this manually because we are not drawing in a UIView)
//
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);                             

for (CGFloat x = 0.0; x<size.width; x+=1.0) {
   for (CGFloat y=0.0; y< size.height; y+=1.0) {
// Set your color here
      CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
      CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(x, y, 1.0, 1.0));
   }
}


// pop context 
//
UIGraphicsPopContext();     


// get a UIImage from the image context- enjoy!!!
//
UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[outputImage retain];

// clean up drawing environment
//
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return [outputImage autorelease];
```

Comment: No, he was using drawRect in a UIView subclass, which would be much slower than drawing in an offscreen image context.

Comment: What makes this much faster? Why is drawing to the offscreen context so much cheaper? I suggest offscreen rendering, too, but directly accessing memory instead of making 25,000 calls to quartz which I *think* (not measured) are the performance bottle neck here.

Comment: That worked, thank you! (Sorry, I'm just now getting back to this).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be fast, you shouldn't call explicit drawing functions for every pixel. You can allocate memory and use `CGBitmapContextCreate` to build an image with the data in that memory - which is basically a bytes array. Do your calculations and write the color information (a-r-g-b) directly into that buffer. You have to do the maths on your own, though, regarding the sub-pixel accuracy (blending).

I don't have an example at hand, but searching for `CGBitmapContextCreate` should head you the right direction.